# Discord.py - Allow command in specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py

i need to use my discord command in specific channel , I'm using @client.command()
I mean if i used my command in another channel will be not working

````
@client.command()
async def w(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(775491463940669480)

    await ctx.send("hello) ```
````

Comment: You only want to use this command on one specific channel, it won't work on others, right?

Comment: yes exactly , how i can do this with @client.command ...etc

Comment: I didn't find anything about that in discord documentation ,, I know it exists of course lol!. But I did not find it :(

Comment: `ctx.channel` is a [discord.channel.TextChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#textchannel) object and has the associated attributes like name and id - does that give you what you need?

Comment: i wanted to make my command allowed on specific channel , anyway sorted , i found it finally lool . i posted the answer . idk if this noob method or no loll :D but anyway It fulfilled my purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is even an easier way to do it without getting the channel. And without having to indent the whole code.

```py
@client.command()
async def w(ctx):
    # exit command if not the desired channel.
    if ctx.channel.id is not 775491463940669480:
        return
    
    #code here
    await ctx.send("hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `ctx.channel` is equal to your specific channel.

```py
@client.command()
async def w(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.id == 775491463940669480:
        await ctx.send("hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is Online")
-
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    cmdChannel = client.get_channel(776179059355942943)
    if message.content.lower().startswith('!w'):
        if message.channel.id == cmdChannel.id:
            #command invoked in command channel - execute it
            await client.process_commands(message)
        else:
            #command attempted in non command channel - redirect user
            await message.channel.send('Write this command in {}'.format(cmdChannel.mention))

@client.command()
async def w(ctx, amount):
    await ctx.send(f"done {amount}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async def is_channel(ctx):   
    return ctx.channel.id = 775491463940669480

@client.command()
@client.check(is_channel)
async def w(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hello)
```

Making the check call the function `is_channel` makes the code simpler and you can resuse it multiple times.